# Openvpn client, force DNS server

Tags: openvpn, dns-server, clients

Our Linux Ubuntu configuration does have a DNS server (Bind 9).
And `resolv.conf` has its

```
  nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

When using `openvpn` client on that Linux, the *nameserver* is not changed (by the VPN server) but I would like to set it - only during the VPN session - to another specific DNS server `x.y.z.t`, by changing the openvpn client config.

Then, when the `openvpn` session ends, *nameserver* should be back to `127.0.0.1`.

Is there a "clean" way (ie a line in the openvpn client config file) to do that?

(Note: The VPN server config cannot be changed)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After more googling, could find the answer - below if it can help someone.

- install *resolvconf* which can save and restore the `resolv.conf` config file
- add a script to be run by *openvpn*, in `/usr/share/openvpn`, named `update-resolv-conf`. The script determines what should be the new `resolv.conf`, and how to restore it (see link below)
- add

these lines

```
  script-security 2
  up /usr/share/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
  down /usr/share/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

in the openvpn client config file.

Read on [this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenVPN#DNS) for more information.

Comment: Newer installs of OpenVPN include this script with the installation. Instead of manually downloading and installing at `/usr/share/openvpn/update-resolv-conf`, you can find it pre-installed at `/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf`.

Comment: Which version of OpenVPN started to include this file?

Comment: A bit late to the party here but I'm using `2.4.6` and it's been installed for me

Answer (score 5):

##### 2022 update (Arch Linux)

To set a public dns server and update resolvconf, add the following to your ovpn client profile file:

```
dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1
script-security 2
up /usr/share/openvpn/contrib/pull-resolv-conf/client.up
down /usr/share/openvpn/contrib/pull-resolv-conf/client.down
```

Comment: You saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `route-up` / `route-down` scripts on your client to alter your configuration on connection setup as you see fit. See the [OpenVPN docs](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html) on details for how to set this up and which variables you might use in these scripts.

Comment: +1, interesting and useful. The *resolvconf* solution via *up* and *down* (above or below dep. on rating..) is however more to the point, and, imo, cleaner.

Comment: @ring0 I would advise using `route-up` instead of `up` to minimize race conditions. When the `up` script is executed, the connection is not yet set up and you have no chance to query the remote resolver you're setting. If you start the OpenVPN client in a situation where the connection setup would not complete, you are putting your resolver into a possibly non-functional state for a prolonged period of time. See the "Script Order of Execution" section in the [OpenVPN man page](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html) for details.

Comment: I did a few tests, and the *up* script is called right when "Initialization Sequence Completed" is reached, not before. Btw cannot find "route-down" in the man.

Answer (score 1):

This was useful information in order to help me fixing this issue.

I'm an arch linux user and what I saw is that when a Linux client is used with Access Server, this one is unable to alter the DNS settings on the client in question not resolving host as it the stands on [OPEN VPN Documentation](https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/admin-guides/182-how-to-connect-to-access-server-with-linux-clients.html)

I created a script which fixes the problem and with a couple of extra parameters handles openvpn connections via command line.

https://gist.github.com/android10/ee5c3e93dbcf9b7b31e6ee768cbfd477

Here is the main command being executed for the connection:

```
  nohup openvpn --config $OVPN_FILE_PATH --askpass $OVPN_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH \
  --script-security 2 \
  --setenv PATH '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin' \
  --up /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved \
  --down /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved \
  --down-pre \
  &>/dev/null &
```

Any feedback is more than appreciated it.

Answer (score -3):

echo "nameserver=w.x.y.z" > /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver=127.0.0.1" >> /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: That seems inexact (think about the DNS search path, and the persistence of the VPN nameserver), but it's also unclear where you want him to put this.

Comment: There should be a space between 'nameserver' and the IP.