# How to configure DNS of OpenVPN client?

Tags: openvpn, centos7, vpn-client

I have an OpenVPN server running with the following config file

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key 
dh dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
tls-crypt myvpn.tlsauth
cipher AES-256-CBC
compress lz4-v2
push "compress lz4-v2"
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
remote-cert-eku "TLS Web Client Authentication"
```

and I have different clients connected, on Debian machines I used the following config file

```
client
tls-client
ca ca.crt
cert pibox.crt
key pibox.key
tls-crypt myvpn.tlsauth
proto tcp
remote X.X.X.X 1194 tcp
dev tun
topology subnet
cipher AES-256-CBC
log /var/log/openvpn.log
pull
script-security 2                     
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

all is working fine, I can access to my VPN and also I have access to the internet, I'm trying to set up a CentOS 7 client for which I used the same config file but since

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

cannot be used, I'm not sure how can I configure the DNS, I research and some people mention `openresolv`, I also tried with

```
pull-filter ignore "dhcp-option DNS"
```

but nothing works, also, I read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/590706/openvpn-client-force-dns-server#590722) but I don't have

```
/usr/share/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
/usr/share/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

**What is the correct procedure to configure the DNS on a CentOS client?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it, what I did was

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
sudo wget https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/macieks/openresolv/repo/epel-7/macieks-openresolv-epel-7.repo
sudo yum update
sudo yum install openresolv
```

it will create `/etc/resolv.conf`

then I modified it to set my custom DNS

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search Home
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

client

```
client
tls-client
ca ca.crt
cert i7box.crt
key i7box.key
tls-crypt myvpn.tlsauth
proto tcp
remote x.x.x.x 1194 tcp
dev tun
topology subnet
cipher AES-256-CBC
log /var/log/openvpn.log
pull
```

also I desabled the automatic DNS and I put static ones, if you know a better method let me know

[GUI static DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C95OI.png)

Comment: This gets overwritten by `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-***` every time I reboot. Any idea on how to make it permanent?

Comment: does this help? https://ma.ttias.be/centos-7-networkmanager-keeps-overwriting-etcresolv-conf/

Comment: Thanks Frederick I also disabled the automatic DNS in `NetworkManager.conf`

Answer (score 1):

on server side (OPenVPN server) go to your `server.conf` file normally it exist vim `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` or `vim /etc/openvpn/server/server.conf`
modify this line according to you desire DNS server

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```

this will modify client side dns setting on the run