# Web browser DNS doesn't work with OpenVPN on Ubuntu 18.0.4

Tags: domain-name-system, openvpn, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to set up OpenVPN to access systems at work. After a few issues with DNS I partially fixed it using the answer here: [Openvpn client, force DNS server](https://serverfault.com/questions/590706/openvpn-client-force-dns-server#590722).

On the command line I can now `nslookup` and `ping` servers successfully with automatic domain searching. However `wget` requests or trying to load internal websites using Firefox fail to resolve the name. Accessing the websites by IP address succeeds.

How do I get name resolution to work correctly for web requests?

Comment: One up-vote and no comments, 5 months have passed. Is this really that hard to solve? I have a work-around which is to add all the hosts I want to access to /etc/hosts, but it is nasty.

Comment: For the last month or two it has been working perfectly. I don't think I did anything to get it to work.